# Splitting a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that the "dx" tag is used to refer to 2 different things, namely, the dx tool in android, and as an abbreviation of "DirectX". It is a fairly low-volume tag, and seems to be split pretty much in half between the two usages.

There is already a "directx" tag, which would be more appropriate than "dx" for that subject-matter.

What would be the best approach to resolve this situation?

I'm thinking the best thing to do would be to create a wiki summary for the dx tag, describing it's intended usage (for the dx android tool), and then to retag any directx related questions with the directx tag.

Or would retagging the questions like that be considered too... picky and/or bad form?

Or is it such a low-volume tag that it's just really not worth it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Introducing appropriate tag wikis and retagging questions seems like a reasonable approach. It's always better to not overload tag meaning unless absolutely necessary.

In this case, [dx](/questions/tagged/dx) and [directx](/questions/tagged/directx) could happily exist side by side and allow people interested in following one or the other to subscribe to the specific tag that interests them.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I wanted to make sure I was on the right track here and wouldn't be stepping on any toes :)